# JPanel BoxLayout allignment going horribly wrong

Tags: java, spring, jpanel

I am simply trying to make a JPanel with two labels. The first one should be in the center of the screen and the other should be in the left of the panel. Unfortunately this does not happen at all.

Here is the code:

```
class Panel extends JPanel {
    public Panel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JLabel title = new JLabel("Label 1");
        title.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        add(title);



        //This following three lines can be commented out for different behaviour
        JLabel source = new JLabel("Label 2");
        source.setAlignmentX(LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        add(source);

        setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
       }
}
```

So if we comment out the 3 lines talking about source "Label 1" does appear in the center of the screen.

However if we add them back in everything goes wonky. Label 1 is no longer centered and Label 2 is actually to the right of label 1.

What is going on here?

Other attempts that have failed:

```
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();

    JLabel title = new JLabel("TITLE:");
    title.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    box.add(title);

    JLabel title2 = new JLabel("TITLE2:");
    title2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    box.add(title2);

    add(box, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: I don't think Box is capable of doing this.  Maybe use GridBag or Spring.

Comment: Did you really mean to stack your components vertically?  If not, you probably should use a [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).

Comment: That's another point I didn't consider.  Try using `Box.createVerticalBox()` or `Box.createHorizontalBox()` as you require.

Comment: @markspace I did not have luck with the box and borderLayout I dont accepts allignments.

Comment: Added my new attempt to the question

Comment: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). Like @VGR said, BorderLayout seems like a good candidate.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentX(float) An interesting thing in the documentation for SetAlignmentX/Y there is an odd mismatch between the intuitive meaning of X and Y and whether it is vertical or horizontal. Check it out

Comment: @J.Doe That aside, it seems like a "square peg in a round hole" kind of situation.

Comment: I dont get it though the box layout looks much more like what I want. I only need horizontal layers stacked. None of the other stuff.